# Applescript (list choices)

Tags: list, applescript

I need som help with a small Applescript.

When i make my choice in the list. Safari always open test3. Maybe someone can help me?

The code

```
set choice to choose from list {"1", "2", "3"}

if choice is "1" then
        tell application "Safari" to open location "http://test1/"


else if choice is "2" then
        tell application "Safari" to open location "http://test2/"

else
        tell application "Safari" to open location "http://test3/"
end if
```

Comment: You didn't say what you expect to happen.

Comment: S/he expects to happen that Safari doesn't always open test3 but sometimes opens test1 or test2. If you know AppleScript, this is clear. No need for further explanations and no need to vote down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result from a "choose from list" dialog is a list. Even if it only has 1 item in the list it's still a list. So you really want "item 1" from the list to get the actual result.

To fix your code change your first line to this...

```
set choice to item 1 of (choose from list {"1", "2", "3"})
```

Comment: If your question has been solved then please mark my answer (check it) so others know you have found a solution. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your code within the Applescript Editor and you look at the Events/Replies area,

[image]

you will see that your selection is returned in braces -  `{"1"}`. They indicate a **list** was returned back to you. This is especially useful if you wanted to choose multiple items from the list using the `with multiple selections allowed` statement.

So, your `if then` statements failed because you were comparing a list `{"1"}` with a string `"1"`. Since all else failed, test3 was the only option.

To fix it, you can pick an item from the list returned, like this

`set choice to item 1 of (choose from list {"1", "2", "3"})`

or convert the selection to text so you are comparing apples with apples :)

`set choice to (choose from list {"1", "2", "3"}) as text`

Hope this helped.